# Writing a recursive function to find how many elements in list are greater than 30

Tags: python, recursion

I want to write a **recursive** function named `greater_than_30(list_nums)` which finds how many numbers in the given list are greater than 30.

eg:

```
list1 = [10, 35, 30, 50]
output - 2
```

Here is the function I have writter:

```
def greater_than_30(list_nums):
    if len(list_nums) == 1:
        if list_nums[0] > 30:
            return 1
            
    else:
        if list_nums[0] > greater_than_30(list_nums[1:]):
            return list_nums[0] 
        else:
            return greater_than_30(list_nums[1:])


>>>a_list = [13, 21, 50, 34, 29, 33]
print(greater_than_30(a_list))
3 #output expected
50 #output gotten
```

Comment: Notwithstanding the excellent Answer from @enke I can't help wondering why you want to do this using recursion.

Comment: @JCaesar this is fairly common programming 101 level question (or rather this+variants of it) to teach the concept of recursion to students

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though I can't understand why you'd want to do this trivial operation recursively, here's a solution:

```
list1 = [13, 21, 50, 34, 29, 33]

def greater_than_30(lst):
    if len(lst) == 0:
        return 0
    return (1 if lst[0] > 30 else 0) + greater_than_30(lst[1:])

print(greater_than_30(list1))
```

**Output:**

```
3
```

Answer (score 4):

You're never actually counting it there. If you replace

```
if list_nums[0] > greater_than_30(list_nums[1:]):
    return list_nums[0]
```

with

```
if list_nums[0] > 30:
    return 1 + greater_than_30(list_nums[1:])
```

it will work as expected.

Comment: The error I'm getting is that its return None

Comment: I made an error, sorry

Comment: The code works fine for me, and yes, it depends on the input. (It `return`s 3)